# Bypass sql injection filtering (whitespace, /, *)

Tags: sql-injection, waf, postgresql

I want to bypass a sql injection waf that replaces `/,*` and whitespaces.

This is a payload I want use :

```
?parameter=22321'union select CAST(normal_column AS bigint),'a','b' from normal_table--
```

But the website replaces the whitespaces with nothing before parse query.

I decided to use `'/**/'` instead of whitespaces but the website filters this too.

what should I do?

Comment: Maybe the instruction chr() can help you

Comment: @MarcoNappi can you give an example for it ?

Comment: `SELECT CHR(65) || CHR(87) || CHR(65) || CHR(69);` this one should be enough

Comment: @MarcoNappi We cant use whitespaces

Comment: In that you can avoid whitespaces in the example above